# Search for code in GitHub using GraphQL (v4 API)

Tags: github, graphql, github-api

I am using the GitHub's GraphQL API to search for files/code containing a particular word.  A simple (contrived) example of a search which in this case is to find the term "beef" in files located in "recipes" (the repo) for "someuser" (the owner for the repo) is shown below:

```
{
  search(query: "beef repo:someuser/recipes", type: REPOSITORY, first: 10) {
    repositoryCount
    edges {
      node {
        ... on Repository {
          name
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I tried this in GitHub's GraphQL Explorer (https://developer.github.com/v4/explorer/) and receive zero results from the search which is incorrect as I can confirm that the word ("beef" in the example above) is in the files in the repo:

```
{
  "data": {
    "search": {
      "repositoryCount": 0,
      "edges": []
    }
  }
}
```

When I try this using GitHub's REST API (v3) via curl, I definitely get results:

```
curl --header 'Accept: application/vnd.github.v3.raw' https://api.github.com/search/code?q=beef+repo:someuser/recipes
```

... So I know that the query (REST v3 API) is valid, and my understanding is that the query string in the GraphQL (v4) API is identical to that for the REST (v3) API.

My questions are:

1. Am I incorrectly using the GitHub GraphQL (v4) API or am I specifying the query string improperly, or am I trying to use functionality that is not yet supported?
2. Is there an example of how to do this that someone can provide (or link to) that illustrates how to search code for specific words?

Comment: If it's this difficult I'm not betting on GraphQL becoming a standard any time soon!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`Type: CODE` is not supported yet. There is no way you can search the code using graphql right now.

Your understanding is right. Just that you are missing one piece. 
The search you are doing is happening against the `type: REPOSITORY`.
if you replace your search with

`search(query: "beef", type: REPOSITORY, first: 10) {`

you will get all the repos having beef in their name.

Comment: two years later and `type: CODE` is still not supported, we still need to use the v3 API for this..

Comment: Make that three years later

Comment: We are at 4 years now :)

Comment: 5 Years! :)))))

Comment: see also the [supported values for search type](https://docs.github.com/en/graphql/reference/enums#searchtype)

Comment: Update: 6 years!!

Answer (score 1):

You can add qualifiers, if you want to search "beef" just in names than change the query like

search(query: "beef in:name", type: REPOSITORY, first: 10) {

for further detail you can look at https://help.github.com/en/articles/searching-for-repositories#search-based-on-the-contents-of-a-repository